# Get a distinct value from Django QuerySet using MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

Does anyone know how to get a distinct value in Django QuerySet? I'm using MySQL db and I couldn't find a solution yet.

The table is:

```
         ID     WORK_YMD    LINE_NM  MODEL_CODE    MAG_NO             PRODC_MAGT_NO 
        118002  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4035
        118003  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4027
        118004  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4039
        118005  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4037
        118006  20191015    PBA-21F BN94-14806W A656MAF00001    BR10BN9414806WA656MAE4038
```

I want to get the model_code considering a `Filter mag_no = "My Variable" Ex:A656MAF00001`

I tried something like this, but didn't work.

```
Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no='A656MAF00001').get('model_code').distinct().order_by()
```

The error is:

> "Too many values to unpack"

Comment: you have several  PRODC_MAGT_NO   for each A656MAF00001      MAG_NO              so the distinct clause return all the rows  with different value  ..  are you sure you are looking for distinct and not for min or max  PRODC_MAGT_NO   related  to MAG_NO

Comment: Try Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no='A656MAF00001').order_by('model_code).distinct('model_code')

Comment: Tks Lancross, but I got the follow error: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by database backend

Comment: Hello scaisEdge, my simple aplication is to the user pass the mag_no and django gives model_code, after that a I gonna include other values to save in another table, it's just to validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no='A656MAF00001').values('model_code').distinct().order_by('-id')
```

You can't give arguments to distinct unless you are using Postgres.

From the docs:

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in
>   order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should
>   apply.

Django [docs distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

**edit**: based on the comment to get the last row.

```
Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no='A656MAF00001').values('model_code').distinct().last().get('model_code')
```

Comment: Really thanks, this definetelly works. But gave a list, possible to get only the last value? I Tried Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no='A656MAF00001').values('model_code').distinct().order_by('-id').last() , but I have {'model_code': 'BN94-14806W'}, how to get only BN94-14806W

Comment: Exactly that, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement on Nalin Dobhal's answer, and in response to your comment to his/her answer, do this:

Magazine.objects.filter(mag_no='A656MAF00001').values('model_code').distinct().order_by('-id').last().get('model_code')

This is because, after invoking last(), you are left with a python dict, and to get a dict's value, you need to use the get('key_name') function. 
As pointed out here:https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#dgetltkeygt-ltdefaultgt

Comment: Thank you Mr. Abouchama, now I got 100% that I want.